# Zero derivative on a connected set

Tags: cv.complex-variables

I apologize in advance for this (not really research level) question whose answer should be well known. Complex differentiability of a function $f:A\to\mathbb C$ for $A\subseteq \mathbb C$ without isolated points is defined as usual as the convegence of difference quotients $$f'(a)=\lim\limits_{A\ni z\to a}\frac{f(z)-f(a)}{z-a}.$$ Assume that $f$ is differentiable at every point of a connected set $A$ with $f'(a)=0$ for every $a\in A$. Does this imply that $f$ is constant?

(Of course, there are many easy situations, e.g., if $A$ is open or a not too irregular curve. It would also help if the convergence of the difference quotients would be in some sense uniform.)

Comment: This does not follow, see this 1936 paper by Whitney: https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4612-2972-8_19

Comment: @DanieleTampieri: If the limit exists, then automatically $\partial f/\partial \bar z=0$. :-)

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki, right! Thanks for pointing it out 

Comment: Thanks, @ChristianRemling. I you upgrade your comment to an aswer, I will, of course, accept it.

Comment: @JochenWengenroth: Thanks, but I just found this in other (MSE) answers and didn't really do much myself.